# Google Cloud Spanner requests enabling on a different project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Here is my code:

```js
// vim:ft=javascript:

const {Spanner} = require('@google-cloud/spanner');
const spanner = new Spanner({projectId: 'gcp-in-action-317405'});

const instance = spanner.instance('test-instance');
const database = instance.database('test-database');
const employees = database.table('employees');

employees.insert([
  {employee_id: 1, name: 'Steve Jobs', start_date: '1976-04-01'},
  {employee_id: 2, name: 'Bill Gates', start_date: '1975-04-04'},
  {employee_id: 3, name: 'Larry Page', start_date: '1976-04-01'}
]).then((date) => {
  console.log('Saved data!', data);
});
```

The code runs then quits with the following errors:

```
(node:24310) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud Spanner API has not been used in project 84555343487 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/spanner.googleapis.com/overview?project=84555343487 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:179:52)
    at listener.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:80:35)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/node_modules/grpc-gcp/build/src/index.js:73:29)
    at InterceptingListenerImpl.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:75:23)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181)
    at process.nextTick (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
(node:24310) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:24310) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:24310) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud Spanner API has not been used in project 84555343487 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/spanner.googleapis.com/overview?project=84555343487 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:179:52)
    at listener.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:80:35)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/node_modules/grpc-gcp/build/src/index.js:73:29)
    at InterceptingListenerImpl.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:75:23)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181)
    at process.nextTick (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
(node:24310) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

For further context, here is the output of `gcloud projects list`:

```
PROJECT_ID                  NAME           PROJECT_NUMBER
gcp-in-action-317405        GCP in Action  827217411854
qibla-finder-1507320565537  Qibla Finder   84555343487
```

Obviously I want to be interacting with "GCP in Action" (827217411854) but Google Cloud thinks I'm dealing with "Qibla Finder" (84555343487), which I haven't developed with for several years. Before anyone asks, I've made certain to run `gcloud config set project gcp-in-action-317405`. How can I point Spanner in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're using Application Default Credentials (`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/some.key`) to authenticate your code.

I suspect the key that you're using, belongs to a Service Account that's owned by `qibla-finder-1507320565537` and, when your code makes the call, the owning project is being checked for the API (and it isn't enabled in it).

You may want to create a new Service Account in `gcp-in-action-317405`, give it the appropriate roles for Spanner etc. and authenticate your code using it.

> **NOTE** You may grant the **existing** Service Account access to Spanner in a different project but you'll still then need to enable the API in `qibla-finder-1507320565537`

##### Update: How to create a Service Account

Using `gcloud` you can create a service account, grant it a suitable role, create a key and export the key with:

```sh
PROJECT=gcp-in-action-317405
ACCOUNT=spanner-user

EMAIL=${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com

# Create Service Account
gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--display-name="Spanner User" \
--description="Used by code to interact with Spanner" \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Grant Service Account Database User role
# https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/iam#roles
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/spanner.databaseUser

# Generate a key for this Service Account
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Use Application Default Credentials
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json

# Run your code
```

Comment: That variable is not set and qibla-finder-1507320565537 was last worked on on a computer that is currently gutted

Comment: I'm willing to try the service account part if you can be a bit more explicit about how to proceed

Comment: Given that `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is not set, I assume you're using your current user account for Application Default Credentials (see: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default). Though that makes the error more curious. Please try my update in my answer.

Comment: Well the gcloud commands all worked but I don't know how to get that JSON file. I looked on the service accounts part of the cloud console for spanner-user but the keys section is empty. I looked in the current directory and so far it's still just one JS file.

Comment: The commands I provided do everything for you. You just need to run your code. The key is created in `${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json`. It's then exported to the `GOOGLE_APPLICATIONS_CREDENTIALS` variable that's assumed by application default credentials.

Comment: Sorry, missed the last one somehow. Very silly. I wish Google Cloud Platform in Action covered ANY of this but what's here works and I will mark this as a correct answer. Well done.